# Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message and Backoff none exhausted for ConsumerRecord

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Below is My method defination for kafka listener and if receive null or empty string for payload i guess I'm getting below error... Can you please help.

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.consumer-topic-name.reservation}", groupId = "${kafka.consumer-group-id.test}",
        containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory",autoStartup = "${kafka.auto-start.consumer.tets}")
public void consumeReservation(String payload, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                               @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String kafkaKey) {}

[org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer #0-0-C-1] ERROR o.s.k.l.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler - Backoff none exhausted for ConsumerRecord(topic = test_topic, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 2, offset = 453473, CreateTime = 1601962346576, serialized key size = 41, serialized value size = -1, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = OPERATION, value = [68, 69, 76, 69, 84, 69]), RecordHeader(key = __Key_TypeId__, value = [99, 108, 75, 101, 121])], isReadOnly = false), key = {
"orgId": "1",
"orderId": "U4000024004"}, value = null)
```

org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method[public void com.demo.test.analytics.testanalytics.consumer.FLReservationKafkaConsumer.consumeReservation(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)]
Bean[com.demo.test.analytics.testanalytics.consumer.FLReservationKafkaConsumer @731702d1];
nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Could not resolve method parameter at index 0 in public void com.demo.test.analytics.testanalytics.consumer.FLReservationKafkaConsumer.consumeReservation(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String): 1 error(s): [Error in object 'payload': codes[];arguments[];
default message[Payload value must not be empty]
], failedMessage = GenericMessage[payload = org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaNull @2d99561c, headers = {
**Key_TypeId** = [B @19a2dc5f, kafka_offset = 453473, OPERATION = [B @7d75c01a, kafka_consumer = org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer @363f44ef, kafka_timestampType = CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId = 0, kafka_receivedMessageKey = {
"orgId": "1",
"orderId": "U4000024004"
}, kafka_receivedTopic = test_1order, kafka_receivedTimestamp = 1601962346576, kafka_groupId = reservation_group_id
}];nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Could not resolve method parameter at index 0 in public void com.demo.test.analytics.testanalytics.consumer.FLReservationKafkaConsumer.consumeReservation(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String): 1 error(s): [Error in object 'payload': codes[];arguments[];
default message[Payload value must not be empty]
],
failedMessage = GenericMessage[payload = org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaNull @2d99561c, headers = {
**Key_TypeId** = [B @19a2dc5f, kafka_offset = 453473, OPERATION = [B @7d75c01a, kafka_consumer = org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer @363f44ef, kafka_timestampType = CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId = 0, kafka_receivedMessageKey = {
"orgId": "1",
"orderId": "U4000024004"
}, kafka_receivedTopic = test_1order, kafka_receivedTimestamp = 1601962346576, kafka_groupId = reservation_group_id
}]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java: 1925)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java: 1913)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java: 1812)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java: 1739)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java: 1636)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java: 1366)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java: 1082)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java: 990)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java: 511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java: 266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java: 748)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Could not resolve method parameter at index 0 in public void com.demo.test.analytics.testanalytics.consumer.FLReservationKafkaConsumer.consumeReservation(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String): 1 error(s): [Error in object 'payload': codes[];arguments[];
default message[Payload value must not be empty]
]
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadMethodArgumentResolver.java: 122)
at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$KafkaNullAwarePayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java: 901)
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java: 117)
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java: 148)
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java: 116)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java: 48)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java: 329)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java: 86)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java: 51)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java: 1880)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java: 1862)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java: 1799)
...8 common frames omitt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify that the payload is not required.

```java
@Payload(required = false) String payload, ...
```

Comment: `required=false` means the argument can be `null`.

Comment: One more thing do you have data, Like If I have 5000 TPS then what would be the proper Spring Kafka Configuration that I need to have in the application...

Comment: It's difficult to provide such guidance without much more information; anyway, don't ask supplemental questions in comments.

Comment: I have to say it's kind of a weird decision to force people to add an additional attribute to allow them to retrieve `null` values. I'm sure there was a reasonably deep discussion about it, and I can see wanting to allow people to avoid null handling, but with tombstones being a conceptual thing in Kafka, I think allowing `null` by default and would have been less surprising.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue here are some solutions I searched.

1. Set the spring.listener.ack-mode as manual/manua-immediate in yaml
2. If the solution above is invalid,try to add containerFactory in
   annotation @KafkaListener like "@KafkaListener(topics =
   {"xxxx"},groupId = "xxxx",containerFactory = "batchFactory")" and
   create a same name bean.

   ```java
   public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> batchFactory(){
       ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String,String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
       factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(batchConsumerConfigs()));
       factory.setBatchListener(true); 
       factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
       return factory;
   }
   ```