# Is it possible to optimize my Custom Deserializer?

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I created a new Custom Deserializer, which when an empty string is present in a json this is returned as a null

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<User> {
@Override
public User deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) throws
    IOException {
    JsonNode node = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
    String firstName = null;
    String lastName = null;
    String age = null;
    String address = null;
    if(node.has("firstName") && !node.get("firstName").asText().isEmpty()) {
        firstName = node.get("firstName").asText();
    }
    if(node.has("lastName") && !node.get("lastName").asText().isEmpty()) {
        lastName = node.get("lastName").asText();
    }
    if(node.has("age") && !node.get("age").asText().isEmpty()) {
        age = node.get("age").asText();
    }
    if(node.has("address") && !node.get("address").asText().isEmpty()) {
        address = node.get("address").asText();
    }
    if(firstName == null && lastName == null && age == null && address == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return new User(firstName, lastName, age, address);
}
```

My problem is from the performance point of view. I would like to optimize the fact of having to change the Deserializer at every possible change of field. Is it possible to optimize yours? I was thinking about using Reflaction but I don't know how to do it. It's possible ?

Comment: Why do you want to optimize it? Is it a performance issue? Or are you thinking about maintenance?

Comment: @Ghokun Maintenance, I don't like having to change the deserializer every time at every possible change of the Json fields

Comment: @Jacket, please, see the [deserializer I provided]((https://stackoverflow.com/a/66630142/13942448)) in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66597864/jsondeserializer-does-not-work-on-the-class-but-only-on-the-single-element-of-th/66630142): it it based on reflection indeed, and I included it in the answer just for this reason, in order to give you a more suitable and maintainable deserializer than the one provided in the other answers which are, more tightly coupled to a specific use case. Please, see the updated version of the code, I think it should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest another approach.
Instead of using a `CustomDeserializer` for `User`,
I would rather write a custom deserializer for `String`.
Then you can use this deserializer for the string properties of
your `User` class, where you want to treat an empty string as null.
This also makes maintenance easier whenever you need to
change the properties of your `User` class.

```
public class User {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomStringDeserializer.class)
    private String firstName;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomStringDeserializer.class)
    private String lastName;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomStringDeserializer.class)
    private String age;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomStringDeserializer.class)
    private String address;
    
    // getters and setters omitted here for brevity
}
```

The custom string deserializer can be implemented very easy
by extending Jackson's `StringDeserializer`.

```
public class CustomStringDeserializer extends StringDeserializer {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String value = super.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        if (value != null && value.isEmpty())
            value = null;     // replace empty string by null
        return value;
    }
}
```